# Failed to add new osd into monitor node in ceph

Tags: ceph

I am trying to add a osd node  by following command

```
ceph-deploy osd prepare ceph-02:/dev/sdb
```

Found error that config file /etc/ceph/ceph.conf exists 
with different content. used `--overwrite-conf` to overwrite.

**How do I use `overwrite-conf`?**

Error log:

```
[ceph_deploy.osd][INFO  ] Distro info: CentOS Linux 7.4.1708 Core

[ceph_deploy.osd][DEBUG ] Deploying osd to ceph-02

[ceph-02][DEBUG ] write cluster configuration to /etc/ceph/{cluster}.conf

[ceph_deploy.osd][ERROR ] RuntimeError: config file /etc/ceph/ceph.conf exists 

with different content; use --overwrite-conf to overwrite

[ceph_deploy][ERROR ] GenericError: Failed to create 1 OSDs
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a normal behavior for a `ceph-deploy` command. Just run `ceph-deploy --overwrite-conf osd prepare ceph-02:/dev/sdb`. This will replace your existing /etc/ceph/ceph.conf. 
This will resolve your issue.